# SFML 2.0 Crashing (Error on window-d-2

Tags: c++, sfml

Using Code::Blocks, W7, Ati Card
I have this silly problem, I tried to compile a sample program from SFML website - http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php
Everything set correctly, I think. When I start (Build and run) It throws out a crash, when looking into crash details it points out window-2-d.
All the .dll files are in the project directory, obviously a dynamic build.
RC from the website, for version 2.0 (I couldn't use 1.6 anyway because of ATI bug)

Tried to use this code to run it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Help?

Comment: this is probably silly of me, but I'd try to define implicit arguments sf::VideoMode(200,200,32). There is 32 by default in the constructor, so it probably won't help, but I'd check, I've already seen a few silly things which shouldn't help but did :)

Comment: @PiotrWadas Nope, didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest Code::Blocks version, which includes GCC 4.7.1, then you have to recompile SFML on your own (or use my [Nightly Builds](http://sfml.my-gate.net/downloads.html)), because the ones provided are only for GCC versions < 4.7.x.

> I couldn't use 1.6 anyway because of ATI bug

SFML 2 is better anyways, so don't worry.